# "org.json.JSONException: Forbidden numeric value : NaN"

Tags: java, android, json

I am having some issues when trying to create a JSONObject from a string.

```
try {
                    JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
                    final JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray("Waypoints");
                    AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObj;
                            try {
                                jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                latL.add(jsonObj.getDouble("Latitude"));
                                lonL.add(jsonObj.getDouble("Longitude"));
                                name.add(jsonObj.getString("Name"));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Error Logs:

```
2018-12-28 14:06:32.394 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink I/System.out: Message received from the server : �����{"Result":0,"Type":"Fds.IFAPI.APIFlightPlan","Bearing":97.74833,"DesiredTrack":113.921631,"DistanceToDestination":20.7412319,"DistanceToNext":20.7412319,"ETAToDestination":NaN,"ETAToNext":NaN,"ETEToDestination":3.63384724,"ETEToNext":3.63384724,"ICAO":null,"NextWaypointLatitude":37.69588,"NextWaypointLongitude":-122.455284,"Track":284.077728,"WaypointName":"DUXBY","Waypoints":[{"Code":"WPT","Latitude":37.613646941754411,"Longitude":-122.35739898939444,"Name":"WPT"},{"Code":null,"Latitude":37.6826,"Longitude":-122.52375,"Name":"KYNNG"},{"Code":null,"Latitude":37.72509444,"Longitude":-122.5029,"Name":"VPSLM"},{"Code":null,"Latitude":37.69588056,"Longitude":-122.45528611,"Name":"DUXBY"}]}
```

> 2018-12-28 14:06:32.396 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Forbidden numeric value: NaN
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.397 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.checkDouble(JSON.java:25)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.397 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:265)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.397 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:384)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.397 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.397 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:159)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.397 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:176)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.397 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at com.virtualflight.virtuallink.MainActivity$SendCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:174)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.398 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at com.virtualflight.virtuallink.MainActivity$SendCommand.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:116)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.398 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.398 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.398 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.398 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.399 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>   2018-12-28 14:06:32.399 30282-30408/com.virtualflight.virtuallink W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Now, I think I know what the issue is but I don't know how to actually fix it. In essence, I think it is because "ETAToDestination" and "ETAToNext" return "NaN" values instead of an Integer or Double, therefore the string cannot be converted to a JSONObject. There will be cases where those 2 values will have a numeric value in them instead of NaN.

Maybe there is some way of suppressing the error on that specific line of code?

Thank you in advance and sorry about the sloppy formatting of my questions contents.

Comment: where are you getting your json string from?

Comment: @FarhanQasim I'm getting it from a game API

Comment: @dragospopa, is that up to your control? Why does it return `NaN`s and can you make it return something else?

Comment: If you look [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) in JSON.stringify part, note 4, `NaN` is not a valid result for JSON.stringify, it must be a `null`. [JSON spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627) also doesn't permit `NaN` values (more precisely, the values not representable by a string of decimal numbers).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The API is not in my control. Thanks for the help but Kousik Mandal's answer worked

Comment: Of course it works, but it only masks the problem. Actual problem is your API has a bug in it, and that should be solved instead of patching every API consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one of the most easy solution is string replace the NaN with whatever you want.

```
myjsonstring = myjsonstring.replaceAll("NaN", -1 /*Or whatever you need*/);

//Now you can do your work as it is
JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
```

Comment: This might work in many cases, but if the JSON is always coming without spaces, one could replace ":NaN," with ":-1,", that would be safer. With regular expressions it would be possible to process also JSON with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
double defaultValue = 0.0;

double myDouble = jsonObj.getDouble("Latitude");
latL.add(Double.isNaN(myDouble) ? defaultValue : myDouble);
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).